# Change text with replaceWith()

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to create a table which when clicking on one of the cells, it replaces it's text content with one already stored value and when clicking a second time to perhaps another cell changes the clicked cell text for the one of the previous click.

I succeed to do it for the first iteration but for the second one, i don't know why the value of the removed cell is stored as null. Here is what I've tried:

html:

```
<table>
    <tr id="l1">
        <td><span>opA</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="l2">
        <td><span>OpB</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="l3">
        <td><span>OpC</span></td>
    </tr>               
    <tr id="l4">
        <td><span>OpD</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
   var removed="firstchange";
     var removed2;
$("#l1, #l2, #l3, #l4").click(function() {
    if($(this).attr("id")=="l1"){
        removed2=$('#l1').find("span").text();
        $('#l1').find("span").replaceWith(removed);
        removed=removed2;
    }else if($(this).attr("id")=="l2"){
        removed2=$('#l2').find("span").text();
        $('#l2').find("span").replaceWith(removed);
        removed=removed2;
    }else if($(this).attr("id")=="l3"){
        removed2=$('#l3').find("span").text();
        $('#l3').find("span").replaceWith(removed);
        removed=removed2;
    }else if($(this).attr("id")=="l4"){
        removed2=$('#l4').find("span").text();
        $('#l4').find("span").replaceWith(removed);
        removed=removed2;
    }   
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure you should be defining the variable inside the function?

Comment: True, i already did that but still it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution doesn't work because [replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) function replaces span element in your code with the provided text. Try more generic solution that change only text inside span and don't replaces span element.

```
var removed="firstchange", 
    removed2;
$("table").on('click','tr',function() {
    var current = $(this).find('span');
    removed2 = current.text();
    current.text(removed);
    removed = removed2;
});
```